# Source files not updating in RubyMine after pulling from heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, rubymine

So, I did the "smart" thing of deleting the local branch where I had just fixed a bunch of stuff and now my only working copy of it is in my current heroku release.  I tried using git pull and also tried using the process of creating a tracking branch to have a local copy of what is currently on heroku, but neither seems to have worked.  When I bring up RubyMine and look at the source files they are the older versions before I updated them with my fixes.  Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?  I've used heroku/git for a little while now but mainly to push updates to heroku.  This is my first time trying to pull code down from it.  I am tempted to try using heroku git:clone but worried that might be a fatal mistake if it stomps on my local stuff and then I have no complete working copy.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does 'I did the "smart" thing of deleting the local branch where I had just fixed a bunch of stuff and now my only working copy of it is in my current heroku release' actually mean? Can you share the commands you used? Same with '[I] also tried using the process of creating a tracking branch to have a local copy of what is currently on heroku'. Finally, 'I've used heroku/git for a little while now but mainly to push updates to heroku'—yes, that's how it's supposed to work. You're not generally supposed to fetch or pull from Heroku. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry my attempt at sarcasm was not clear. I put smart in quotes to hint maybe i should not have done that. Your right about way things are suppose to work but now that I'm in this situation trying to find way to create local git branch of current heroku release. I found notes on using git clone or creating a local tracking branch of heroku but have not gotten either to work yet.  Thanks.

Comment: I meant to say i have tried tracking branch and considering using heroku git:clone. Haven't tried that yet due to not knowing how it will effect current local git repo of same heroku rails app.

Comment: So you pushed changes to Heroku and then deleted the branch you pushed?

Comment: Yes, and now I'm trying to find a way to make up for that by creating a new local branch based on the copy i pushed up to heroku.

Comment: Then you should have a local tracking branch `heroku/master` (assuming your Heroku remote is called `heroku`, which is the default if you let the `heroku` tool set it up). Try `git branch heroku/master new-branch` to create a new local branch `new-branch` based on `heroku/master`. If that works I'll add a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  If you want to post it as an answer I'd be glad to accept it since I know it's a valid approach and matches what I have seen suggested.  I actually ended up having to take a different approach.  I used "git reflog" to get a listing of recent commits with their related sha1 hashs, found one close to just before where I deleted the branch I needed and then did "git branch [branch-name] <sha1 hash #>.  git was able to use the sha1 hash from the previous commit to create a new branch.  I'm typing this from memory so git branch command might be little diff than I recall.